# Making WebStorm add style={} instead of style=""

Tags: reactjs, webstorm

Working on React with WebStorm I'd love to set up WebStorm's code completion to offer:

```
<div style={}...
```

instead of:

```
<div style=""...
```

Any way to achieve this behaviour?

Answer (score 3):

Upgrade to 2016.2.  It does that now.

From their [What's new](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/whatsnew/):

> WebStorm can now provide code completion and resolve for component
>   properties defined using propTypes. For React events the IDE will
>   automatically add {} instead of "". Non-DOM attributes are no longer
>   marked as unresolved, and similarly, component lifecycle methods are
>   not marked as unused anymore.

Comment: PS I just tried it (typed `<div styl` and hit TAB and I got `<div style={}`